Null Pointer Exception while reading Hbase Dataframe
**When I load an Hbase table I get this exception: **
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:171)
    at es.*.*.soporte.HBaseUtils.ExportHBaseTables$.getOfertasPre(ExportHBaseTables.scala:98)
    at es.*.*.soporte.HBaseUtils.ExportHBaseTables$.main(ExportHBaseTables.scala:51)
    at es.*.*.soporte.HBaseUtils.ExportHBaseTables.main(ExportHBaseTables.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:739)

My spark session has these conf:
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBase Utils Export")
    conf.set("spark.shuffle.blockTransferService", "nio")
    conf.set("spark.storage.blockManagerHeartBeatMs", "300000")
    conf.set("spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs", "300000")
    conf.set("spark.worker.timeout", "90000")
    conf.set("spark.network.timeout", "600")
    conf.set("spark.akka.timeout", "90000")
    conf.set("spark.rpc.retry.wait", "30000")
    conf.set("spark.akka.frameSize", "2047")
    conf.set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.5")
    conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
    conf.set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Xss1024m")
    conf.set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Xss1024m")
    conf.set("spark.kryo.referenceTracking", "true")

val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

and this .load() is where it fails:
val hbaseOptions = Map(
  "hbase.columns.mapping" -> s"rowkey STRING :key, datos STRING Ofertas:Datos",
  "hbase.table" -> s"default:$name"
)

val ofertasDF: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")
  .options(hbaseOptions)
  .load()

This is my Spark Submit:
spark3-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-java-options "-DCGF_FILE=path/config/.cfg -DTABLAS_CGF_FILE=path/config/tablas.cfg" --principal user --keytab /home/user/kt/.keytab --files /etc/hbase/conf.cloudera.hbase/hbase-site.xml --class es...soporte.HBaseUtils.ExportHBaseTables /home/user/jars_test/soporte.jar
